# How to get segmentation data from Snowflake Table in API efficiently and cost-effectively?

Tags: sql, api, rest, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I have a segmentation project I am working on for my company and we have to create a pipeline to gather data from our app users and when they fit a segment then the app will receive that information and do something with it (not in my scope). So currently, the client connects and authenticates to an endpoint that allows their client to send JSON data to an Elasticsearch cluster (app started, level completed, etc). I'm then using an Azure Function to grab the live data every 5 minutes and store it in an Azure Blob Storage which then creates a queue that Snowflake reads and ingests the JSON files. We'd then use Snowflake to run a task per segment (that will be decided by the analysts or executives) and the data will be outputted to a table like the one below:

| AccountID | Game | SegmentID | CreatedAt | DeletedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | Game 1 | 1 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-21 |
| 123456789 | Game 1 | 2 | 2021-04-20 |  |
| 123456789 | Game 1 | 3 | 2021-04-20 |  |

Where **SegmentID** can represent something like

| SegmentID | SegmentType | SegmentDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 Day Streak | User played for 5 consecutive days |
| 2 | 10 Day Streak | User played for 10 consecutive days |
| 3 | 15 Day Streak | User played for 15 consecutive days |

In the next step of the pipeline, the same API the user authenticated with should post a request when the game boots up to grab all the segments that the user matches. The dev team will then decide where, when in the session and how to use the information to personalize content. Something like:

```
select
  SegmentID
from
  SegmentTable
where
  AccountID='{AccountID the App authenticated with}' and
  Game='{Game the App authenticated with}' and
  DeletedAt is null
```

Response:

| SegmentID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Serialised:

```
{"SegmentID": [2,3]}
```

We expect to have about 300K-500K users per day. My question would be, what would be the most efficient and cost-effective way to get this information from Snowflake back to the client so that this amount of users wouldn't have issues when querying the same endpoint and it won't be costly.

Comment: Hi - you seem to be describing a transactional process, in which case I'm wondering why you are using Snowflake - which is an analytics DB? If you're trying to extract single records from Snowflake then the performance is going to be, relatively, pretty bad and pretty expensive. If you can, it would make more sense to bulk load data into Snowflake, bulk process it and then export the results to a DB more suited to supporting a transactional dataflow

Comment: I don't think something that is loading data every 5 minutes and then running a select across a table based on a segment of data would be considered transactional.  I definitely think Snowflake can handle the scenario being presented here.

Comment: @NickW it doesn't have to be Snowflake. Snowflake is our data warehouse and wanted to leverage this if possible. We would still need to use Snowflake to compile the segments in the final SegmentTable based on whatever logic we are given.

Comment: @MikeWalton It's the final part that I would suggest is transactional: returning the segments for a single user and running this query for 300K-500K users per day. Obviously, Snowflake could support this but I would question whether, in an ideal world, this is the best solution. If the Snowflake performance is good enough, and the cost acceptable, then using Snowflake, rather than standing up an alternative and populating it with data, may make more sense - depends on the questioner's specific circumstances

Comment: @NickW With that kind of volume, a multi-cluster of XS warehouses that don't shut down would likely cost about the same as adding another solution, and most of the queries would then come from cache and be very fast.  I've seen this work at other Snowflake customers.  But you are correct....that is a high volume of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so a bit of a workaround, but I created an external function on Snowflake (using Azure Functions) that upserts data in a local MongoDB cluster. So the API connects to the MongoDB instance which can handle the large volume of concurrent connections and since it is on a local server it is quite cheap. The only cost is the data transfer from Snowflake to MongoDB and the running of the App Service Plan on Azure Functions (could not use consumption-based as to send data to our internal server I needed to create a VNET, NAT Gateway and a Static Outbound IP Address in Azure) and the API Management Service I had to create in Azure.

So how it works? For each stored procedure in Snowflake, at the end I am collecting the segments which have changed (New row or DELETED_AT not null) and triggering the external function which upserts the data in MongoDB using the pymongo client.